# What's the difference between these codes?

Tags: javascript, jquery, prototype-oriented

```
function Demo() {
   this.show1 = function() { alert(1) }
}

Demo.prototype.show2 = function() { alert(2) }

var d = new Demo
d.show1()
d.show2()
```

`show1` and `show2` can both alert number.

Is there any difference between these two?

Comment: Except re-usability, readability, etc? Read this for instance: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/572897/how-does-javascript-prototype-work

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, if you initialize that method inside the constructor, e.g. (`this.method = function () {};`), all of your 1000 object instances will have a function object as own property.

Well, it's the most **lightweight** way to go, let's say you have a method in the prototype of certain constructor, and you create 1000 object instances, all those objects will have your method in their prototype chain, and all of them will refer to only one function object.

In the second case, only those objects, which get created after the `Demo.prototype.show2 = function(){alert(2)}` will get the code. :)

#### Example

**Your code**

```
function Demo(){
   this.show1 = function(){alert(1)}
}

Demo.prototype.show2 = function(){alert(2)}

var d = new Demo
d.show1()
d.show2()
```

**Other Case**

```
function Demo(){
   this.show1 = function(){alert(1)}
}

var d = new Demo

Demo.prototype.show2 = function(){alert(2)}

d.show1()
d.show2()
```

Answer (score 2):

`show1` is replicated on every new instance. `show2` is shared.

Comment: do you mean that the second case is somehow similar to static methods but the first is non-static if compared with java?

Comment: @HussainAl-Mutawa: I think so yes, similar to static methods but you have access to `this` and it requires an instance of the object to be used.